# How to get DB Information and make list in SQLite , C#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from SQLite in C# and put it into an array.

```cs
   //class
        public class DBStudentsInfo
        {
            public int uid { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string[] ManyPoints { get; set; }
            public string FinalPoint { get; set; }
            public string Memo { get; set; }
            public string Grade { get; set; }
        }
```

I want to put the information from the DB into a class object. Example: DB status:

uid: 1, name: "ff", number: "1"...

// class object

DBStudentInfo information = new DBStudentInfo ();

info.Name = ...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework which is ORM (Object Relational Mapper).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

if you have an existing database, you can use Database First Approach
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/database-first-approach-in-entity-framework/